# How to select data from table to get output in transpose or crosstab manner?

Tags: mysql, case, select-query

I have a table reportdata with below values :

```
 reportdata       memberCount     monthname     year
Assigned user        588           February     2017
Assigned user        2             January      2017
Assigned user        22            May          2017
FHD                  571           February     2017
FHD                  15            May          2017
ICM                  1             May          2017
sortingCompleted     1             February     2017
sortingCompleted     2             May          2017
```

I want output like :

```
   reportdata           January   February      May
    Assigned user           2       588          22
       FHD                  0       571          15
       ICM                  0        0            1
   sortingCompleted         0        1            2
```

I have tried below query :

```
select d.reportdata,
CASE WHEN d.monthname='January' THEN d.MemberCount END AS January,
CASE WHEN d.monthname='February' THEN d.MemberCount END AS February,  
CASE WHEN d.monthname='May' THEN d.MemberCount END AS May from
(
select reportdata, memberCount,monthname
from cme_report where year='2017'
) as d
```

Please suggest the way to get expected output. Thank is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT
    reportdata,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (monthname = 'January') THEN memberCount ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (monthname = 'February') THEN memberCount ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (monthname = 'May') THEN memberCount ELSE 0 END) AS 'May', 
FROM reportdata
WHERE year = '2017'
GROUP BY reportdata
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Sebastian Brosch , this is working perfectly fine..... Thanks a lot....